# Главное — не сдаваться(,) в жизни любого

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, присоединительная-конструкция

Нужна запятая?

> Главное — не сдаваться(,) в жизни любого.

Comment: Не знаваться?  В жизни любого кого? Контекст неясный, поэтому порядок слов кажется неестественным. Это можно как-то исправить?  (Кстати, я минусы за вопросы не ставлю, ставит кто-то еще.)

Comment: @Sharon В этом я с вами согласен, необходимо дополнить.

Comment: @Максим, придется  вам это сделать. Тоже интересно.  Вам нравится придумывать ситуацию для отдельной фразы?

Comment: @Sharon Почему мне?) Я же не знаю, что Леопольд имел в виду. Не по вопросу и по поводу минусов: я тоже не минусую его вопросы и не знаю кто. Вопросы Леопольда в последнее время только разоряются (в плане голосов).

Comment: Наверное, есть причины.   Они интересны по существу, но стилизация настолько затемняет содержание, что их просто не понимают.  Ваши вопросы более естественные и тоже интересные, как я думаю. Кстати, мне понятна эта тема, контекст придумать несложно. Попробуйте)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Диалог**

— *Он мой герой! Многого достиг, не сдавался перед трудностями.*

— *Ну, в его жизни просто нельзя было иначе.*

— *Главное — не сдаваться, *в жизни любого*.*

***В жизни любого*** — неполный присоединительный оборот, восстанавливается по контексту (= причем это верно в жизни любого человека).

Answer (score 3):

Обычный порядок слов:
*Главное в жизни любого [человека] — не сдаваться.*

В исходном предложении без знака не обойтись.
*Не сдаваться в жизни любого* (?) — нет, так не пойдёт. Запятая возможна, но после выраженной паузы, обозначенной тире, она плохо показывает присоединение.  Я бы поставил точку:
***Главное — не сдаваться. В жизни любого.***
Насколько необходимо существительное к слову "любой" — покажет контекст. Ни в [Нацкорпусе](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CkoqGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCJwolCiMKA3JlcRIcChrQkiDQttC40LfQvdC4INC70Y7QsdC%2B0LPQvjAB), ни на сайте [Картаслов.ру](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D0%B2+%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8+%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE) нет предложений без какой-либо "добавки" к словосочетанию "**в жизни любого**".

> [**ЛЮБОЙ**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?word=%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9&all=x) <...>  II. ***местоим. сущ.*** **1.** ***только м.:*** любой, -ого. Всякий, каждый человек; какой угодно человек. *Он мог рассказать свою историю любому.*